# Selenium Python - CORS issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to login to my dvd.netflix account using Selenium Python but I keep getting incorrect login information (despite entering the correct username and password) because the auth request failed due to cors error.

This is the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://dvd.netflix.com/SignIn')

username_input = '//*[@id="email"]'
password_input = '//*[@id="password"]'
login_submit = '//*[@id="signin"]/button'

driver.find_element_by_xpath(username_input).send_keys("justtest0219@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_input).send_keys("12345")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(login_submit).click()
```

The error I get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://portal.dvd.netflix.com/auth/authenticate' from origin 'https://dvd.netflix.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I also tried to disable CORS Check but still can't login, If I try to login manually with WebDriver for Chrome it does login

Comment: Update the question with the error you see.

Comment: Done. The error is in the console log.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you are trying to invoke `send_keys()` too early even before the [JavaScript enabled webelements have completely rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233385/request-fully-javascript-rendered-html-source-from-a-website-and-find-all-iframe/47237075#47237075).

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://dvd.netflix.com/SignIn')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='email']"))).send_keys("justtest0219@gmail.com")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

In-case the error still occurs you may require to add the following argument:

- **`--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`**

So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://dvd.netflix.com/SignIn')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='email']"))).send_keys("justtest0219@gmail.com")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to set header “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” to selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795355/how-to-set-header-access-control-allow-origin-to-selenium-webdriver/62797348#62797348)
- [Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin “http://localhost:8080” from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163151/uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8080-from/51174271#51174271)
- [Error: Permission denied to access property “x” due to same/cross origin policy using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621387/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-x-due-to-same-cross-origin-policy/55628911#55628911)
- [SecurityError: Permission denied to access property “document” on cross-origin object error clicking on download link in iframe using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643276/securityerror-permission-denied-to-access-property-document-on-cross-origin-o/62643573#62643573)

Comment: Still getting the same error. If I open the login page using selenium and I fill out the form manually it works. Even if I fill only the email using selenium and the password manually or only defining find_element_by_... I get the error.

Comment: @EmmaGrove Possibly due to zonal restrictrictions I get a _Page Not Found_ even on accessing the page manually. Hence provided a few other references for your reference.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help! The website is not available in some countries. Use USA Vpn if you have it if you don't I can give you mine

Comment: @EmmaGrove Sure. Let's discuss the issue in details within [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)

Comment: You didn't respond

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed this by using firefox geckodriver instead of chrome webdriver.**